# Can't get PHP to parse with NGINX/FastCGI/PHP

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-16.04, fastcgi

So I spent the better part of last night trying to get my ec2 instance setup with nginx and php7.2. I got everything installed and I edited the server block in my nginx.conf with the values I thought needed to be there...and I had 502 errors for about an hour. But, I troubleshot that, and now I'm to a point where all I have is a blank screen. (my domain is shinesolar.app by the way). Here is my nginx config for php:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

And I understand that almost everything there is commented out, but that is because I'm pretty sure that's the only thing I needed. What did I do wrong here?

Also, for completeness sake, I have an index.php in my webroot that is supposed to echo `phpinfo();`

**EDIT:**

There is nothing in /var/log/nginx/error.log

**EDIT #2**

Here is my current php config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

**Edit 3**

```
    server {
        listen    443 ssl http2;
        server_name    shinesolar.app www.shinesolar.app;
        access_log    /var/www/access_log/webserver_access.log;
        root /var/www/public_html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy
            autoindex off;
        }

    location @proxy {
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shinesolar.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/shinesolar.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


    server {
    if ($host = www.shinesolar.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = shinesolar.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name    shinesolar.app www.shinesolar.app;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be related to PHP. The TLS handshake doesn't even complete. Please post the complete `server` block and anything `include`d from it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry, I was messing with some subdomain stuff I'm trying to do in the meantime, it's restored. I can still post the server block if need be, but I don't think its necessary now

Comment: OK, what is in the error log?

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's what is really confusing...in /var/log/nginx/error.log, the only error I have is a 404 on a favicon (which makes sense because I don't have a favicon in there). So I really have no idea where to go

Comment: Why is SCRIPT_FILENAME commented out? fpm uses that variable to locate the script that needs to be executed. You are probably getting PHPFPM errors which are not being logged by `nginx`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I just checked the fpm log, I see no errors, just startup notices

Comment: @RichardSmith Also, I just uncommented that line, and now I'm getting a 404 error on shinesolar.app

Comment: That's not necessarily supposed to be `/scripts`. That should be your `$document_root`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton updated to current config and I still have the 404 error

Comment: Something else is probably wrong. Post the complete `server` block.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Posted

Comment: I see "Digital Snitch"?! Are you sure your site is broken?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, because that's just the html there. Nothing there is php, I've got stuff behind it that I want processed by php. I know that can be confusing

Comment: OK, then can you provide a URL that is actually not working but should be?